# Transaction rollback with loop calling inner method

Tags: java, ejb

Hello i have a question about transaction rollback in one bean. I am trying to allow process to ignore bad record and continue with rest. As in example. If `db.update` will throw unchecked exception it will rollback all changes?

```
@Stateless
public class klass{
 @Transational(NEVER)
 public methodA(){
 list = db.getList();
 for(i : list){
  methodB(i);
 }

 @Transactional(REQUIRE_NEW)
 public methodB(arg){
  try{
  db.update(arg, CLOSE);
  }catch(Exception){}
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To active new transaction there are two options:

1. SessionContext.getBusinessObject(local_interface).method_call
2. Calling bean from another bean.

Reason why you need to do this is because container needs to intercept your call. And it can only do that when you are using injected or look-up instance.

Answer (score 0):

Need to call it from another bean. https://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/how_to_self_invoke_ejb